# What does the 'I' suffix means?

Tags: c, integer, clang, literals, suffix

```
unsigned a = 5;
int b = a - 1I;
printf("b=%d", b);
```

Run these codes on Android/iOS, you will get a wield result like "b=5". 
What does the 'I' suffix means?

Comment: i think it is an imaginary number literal, which is a compiler-specific language extension. Are you using the gcc compiler?

Comment: clang for Android & iOS

Comment: Suggest adding a language tag. Maybe also mention which compiler is in use

Comment: **I** stands for complex literal. Refer [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i).